when running sls it says stack not found
I've manually deleted a cloudformation stack. Now, when I try to run same sls which I ran earlier it throws
the code is running this aws code pipeline using aws code build and the command being used in buildspec.yml is sls deploy
s:sls:aws:request: request error: #3 - CloudFormation.listStackResources ValidationError: Stack with id cs-user-api-dev does not exist
s: ValidationError: Stack with id cs-user-api-dev does not exist 

I've tried. here is my sls file. this sls creates a lambda and api gateway
service: cs-user-api

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  role: lambdaIAMRole
  stage: ${opt:stage,'local'}
  region: ${opt:region,'us-east-1'}
  environment:
    APP_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: ${aws:accountId}
    PARAMETER_STORE_NAME: cs-${self:provider.stage}
    JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRE_IN_HOURS: 12
  versionFunctions: false
  deploymentBucket:
     name: cs-deployments-bucket-${self:provider.stage}-${aws:accountId}
     serverSideEncryption: AES256
  httpApi:
    id: ${env:HTTP_API_ID}
  stackTags:
    'ProjectId': 'CaseStory'
    'ApplicationId': 'UserApi'
    'Environment': ${self:provider.stage}
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - Ref: lambdaSecurityGroup
    subnetIds:
      - ${env:subnetid_1}
      - ${env:subnetid_2}

functions:
  handler:
    name: ${self:service}-fun-${self:provider.stage}
    handler: src/handler.handler
    timeout: 20
    memorySize: 256
    events: ${file(./serverless-routes.js)}
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:${env:REGION}:${aws:accountId}:layer:common-layer-${env:STAGE}:${env:commonlayertag}
      - arn:aws:lambda:${env:REGION}:${aws:accountId}:layer:user-api-layer-${env:STAGE}:${env:userapilayertag}

plugins:
  # - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-split-stacks


  # customDomain:
  #   domainName: ${env:DOMAIN_NAME}
  #   stage: $default
  #   createRoute53Record: true
  #   endpointType: 'regional'
  #   certificateArn: ${env:CERTIFICATE_ARN}
  #   basePath: "users"


package:
  exclude:
    - .gitignore
    - .git/**
    - node_modules/**
    - trigger-*
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - README.md
    - serverless-routes.js

resources:
  Resources:
    lambdaIAMRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: ${self:service}-role-${self:provider.stage}
        Tags: ${self:custom.tag}
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Action:
                    - ssm:GetParameter
                  Effect: 'Allow'
                  Resource:
                    - arn:aws:ssm:${self:provider.region}:${aws:accountId}:parameter/${self:provider.environment.PARAMETER_STORE_NAME}
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - kms:Decrypt
                  Resource:
                    - ${env:testkmsarn}
            PolicyName: ${self:service}-policy-${self:provider.stage}
    lambdaSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupName: ${self:service}-sg-${self:provider.stage}
        GroupDescription: Security group for ${self:service} lambda function
        VpcId: ${env:vpc_id}
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 443
            ToPort: 443
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

custom:
  env:
    prod:
      ACCOUNT_ID: 00000000000000
      VPCE_ONE: vpce-000000
      VPC_ID: vpc-0000
      SN_ONE: sn-0000
      VPC_IP_RANGE: 0.0.0.0/0
      HTTP_API_ID: 1
    dev:
      ACCOUNT_ID: 00000000000000
      VPCE_ONE: vpc-00000000000000
      VPC_ID: vpc-00000000000000
      SN_ONE: subnet-00000000000000
      VPC_IP_RANGE: 172.31.0.0/16
      HTTP_API_ID: 00000000000000
    qa:
      ACCOUNT_ID: 00000000000000
      VPCE_ONE: vpc-00000000000000
      VPC_ID: vpc-00000000000000
      SN_ONE: subnet-00000000000000
      VPC_IP_RANGE: 172.31.0.0/16
      HTTP_API_ID: 1
    local:
      ACCOUNT_ID: 00000000000000
      VPCE_ONE: vpc-00000000000000
      VPC_ID: vpc-00000000000000
      SN_ONE: subnet-00000000000000
      VPC_IP_RANGE: 172.31.0.0/16
      HTTP_API_ID: 1
  tag:
    - Key: ProjectId
      Value: CaseStory
    - Key: ApplicationId
      Value: UserApi
    - Key: Environment
      Value: ${self:provider.stage}

  splitStacks:
    nestedStackCount: 40 # Controls the number of created nested stacks
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true

